# Table flickering when using ipywidgets interactive

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, plotly-python

I'm trying to make an interactive table which fetches data from csv file. But the table keeps flickering when updates from the server.

I had tried this, but it doesn't work.
https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html?highlight=flickering#Flickering-and-jumping-output

Here is demo code. You could see the flickering in Jupyter notebook.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive

def demo_table(row):
    fig = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Table(
            header=dict(values=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'],
                line = dict(color='#7D7F80'),
                fill = dict(color='#a1c3d1'),
                align = ['left'] * 5),
            cells=dict(values=[[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]],
                line = dict(color='#7D7F80'),
                fill = dict(color='#EDFAFF'),
                align = ['left'] * 5)
        )
    ])
    fig.show()

play = widgets.Play(
    interval=1000,
    value=0,
    min=0,
    max=100,
    step=1,
    description="Press play",
    disabled=False
)

slider = widgets.IntSlider()
widgets.jslink((play, 'value'), (slider, 'value'))
display(widgets.HBox([play]))

interactive_plot=interactive(demo_table, row=slider)
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '350px'
interactive_plot
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a decent solution for this?